# How to create chat functionality same as linkedIn using signalR

Tags: signalr, dotnetnuke

I need to create chat functionality (same as linkedIn messaging) in DNN. How to do that in DNN(C#)?

Answer (score 0):

Not supprisngly, example that Microsoft uses to explain SignalR usage is [chat app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

And chat is also common target for many [SignalR tutorials on the web](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room)

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post here. http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/151246/using-signalr-with-dotnetnuke-modules

Older article but still should be relevant.